# How to get I-beam cursor when inline editing Vaadin Grid Pro contents

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the mouse cursor to an I-beam when mousing over a Vaadin Grid Pro inline editable field to give the user a hint that the cell is in fact editable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, by setting the css property `cursor: text` on cells with the `editable-cell` part name.

There's 3 different ways to do this:

**#1** Load a stylesheet into the `vaadin-grid-pro` component using `@CssImport(value="your-stylesheet.css", themeFor="vaadin-grid-pro")`

**#2** If you're using the [new theme folder format](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/ds/customization/custom-theme/#vaadin-component-styles) (with a `frontend/themes/<themename>` folder in your project), add a stylesheet called `vaadin-grid-pro.css` into the theme's `components` subfolder.

In both above cases, add this block to the stylesheet:

```
[part~="editable-cell"] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
    cursor: text;
}
```

While you're at it, you can also apply e.g. a background color to editable cells to make them even more distinct:

```
[part~="editable-cell"] {
    background: var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
}
```

**#3** Alternatively, you can just add these two style blocks to your app's global stylesheet (typically called styles.css):

```
vaadin-grid-pro::part(editable-cell) {
    --grid-cell-cursor: text;
    /* And, optionally, for that background color: */
    background: var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
}

vaadin-grid-cell-content {
    cursor: var(--grid-cell-cursor, default);
}
```

(One caveat here is that this only works with modern browsers, not with IE11 or pre-2020 versions of Edge, but it's convenient in that you don't need to add a separate stylesheet for Grid Pro just for this, unless you already have one.)

Comment: Thanks Rolf. I added the CSS to the global style sheet and it worked like a charm.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please mark it accepted :)